# I'm getting "Event processing aborted during augmentation" when I try to send a custom event

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I have a system that is basically for reading papers online, and it has a page flipping functionality.
I successfully installed GA4, and when the site initially loads, I get two events:
page_view: which sends it automatically.
page_changed_on_load: sent by me, to corroborate that the event sending is working correctly.

I can see in the console, that both events are sent successfully

[image]

This is the initial code, with which I send those two events:

```
<script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];

    function gtag() {
        dataLayer.push(arguments);
    }
    gtag('js', new Date());
    gtag('config', G-0HP81XXXXXXX');
    gtag('event', 'page_changed_on_load');
</script>
```

Then I have a javascript method onOpRg(), which is the one in charge of changing the page, where I am calling another method that I create called GA4_pageview()

This last method is quite simple, and made according to the GA4 documentation to send events:

```
function GA4_pageview() {
    gtag('event', 'page_changed_on_load');
}
```

The big thing, is that when I execute this last method, the events don't arrive to the analytics. And enabling the Google Analytics Debugger, I see that I get the following message:

[image]

I have searched everywhere for an explanation and I have not been able to find anything.

Can anyone help me with this? I can't make sense of it.

I expect that the event hit GA4, but doesn't.